# Could anyone ID this accent?

Tags: australian-english, new-zealand-english

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_QckQZHa1s (the first person to speak)

I was told it's Australian, but the Australians I met sounded very different.

Comment: I'm guessing it's fake Aussie.  Or maybe he's supposed to be a Brit.

Comment: To me, sounds like an American actor faking an Aussie accent. Track down the cast-list for that episode and you have part of an answer.

Comment: Note that there are different varieties of Australian accent, which may explain why the Australians you've met sounded different. I'm Australian. To me it sounds like someone putting on an Australian accent, or possibly an Australian exaggerating their natural accent (sometimes directors think an Australian actor's normal accent doesn't sound Australian enough).